# Not sure what to do next to optimize

Tags: database

I've got a reasonably large site that I've been developing for some time in a test directory. I have a database about 160 MB, about 100 pages, and over 1000 posts. There are few comments at this time.

I've run an image optimization plugin (imagify), I've deleted old revisions and used WP Cleaup optimizer to delete transients, orphaned data, etc. I've optimized the database both via cpanel and via wp-optimize.

The load speed is still insanely slow - 7 to 12 seconds and no one else is even accessing my site yet. P3 profiler crashes my site :)

I've read a lot of articles on optimization but I'm not sure where to go next. Any ideas? Thank you! I'm mostly just designing it and am not too savvy on back end technology :)

I did read somewhere that the wp-postmeta can become bloated with useless stuff if you import posts from blogger which I did some time ago, but I don't know enough to explore that. Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be useful to analyze where the bottleneck is in rendering pages. Use the Developer mode of your browser (usually via F12) and then use the Network tab to see the load times of the various parts of the page.

Maybe the problem is in images, or 'off-site' Javascript code, or any other off-site item that is included in pages. Maybe it is an inefficient template, or perhaps a plugin causing the problem. Looking at page load times will help.

There are also plugins that will show you all kinds of info about database query times. One is described here: http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/how-to-add-a-wordpress-query-monitor-on-your-site/ .

Looking at page load times might give you a direction to start concentrating on. If it is a database problem, a query analysis plugin might help.

Comment: Thank you! I look forward to trying these suggestions! I really appreciate it!

Comment: No problem. If my answer was helpful, an upvote and checkmark is always appreciated.

Comment: Thanks! Will do :) This site doesn't display my upvotes yet because I'm new but they say it is recorded :)